# How to make slide in transition for ListTile in listview in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am making an app whose structure is very simple.

A `ListView` with `Listtiles` in it.
I want to add animation such that when the screen is opened the `listtiles` slide in.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter provides a [AnimatedList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html) Widget.

Perhaps this native widget will give you the desired output